# Google App Engine Launcher Does Not Launch Even If PIL Is Installed

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine

Problem:  Sometimes GAE-python runs locally on my OSX.  Sometimes it doesn't.  When it doesn't I get the following error:

WARNING  2013-12-22 02:03:24,811 api_server.py:331] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 197, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 193, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 872, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 865, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 692, in start
    apis.start()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 137, in start
    super(APIServer, self).start()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 317, in start
    raise BindError('Unable to find a consistent port for %s' % host)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to find a consistent port for localhost
```

But the weird thing is that I do have PIL installed. I know this because (a) I installed it and (b) GAE does launch some times.

What could be the issue?

Comment: It is only a warning; it won't stop your development server from launching. Something else is wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  The rest of the error message reads:

Comment: The server startup failed because it could not find a network address and port to bind to. Most likely there is (still) another server running bound to the port.

Comment: if this is the duplicate, I'm not sure how to get access to my host files?  Sorry, I'm an amateur.

Comment: There are multiple possibilities listed in different answers. On Mac OS X, the hosts file is located at `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: got it.  well it does not look like a duplicate.  my local host is unique: 127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

Comment: The other question handles all possibilities. Look through the other answers as well.

Comment: Ah the answer by phoenixgrey provided a partial solution.  GAE runs when the internet is off.  But when the internet is on, GAE gives the above error.